# On Change navigate to url value from within an array

Tags: jquery

I have a select menu that is pulling all of its options from an array of objects. See below. I want to have the menu navigate to each's state's url value on change and open in a new tab, but what I have is not firing correctly. I have an if/else statement that keeps firing back 'false' as it is not recognizing a url value.

```
let states = [
      {id: 1, state: "Alabama", district: "1st District", url:"www.google.com"},
      {id: 2, state: "Alabama", district: "2nd District", url:"www.google.com"},
      {id: 3, state: "Alabama", district: "3rd District", url:"www.google.com"},
      {id: 4, state: "Alabama", district: "4th District", url:"www.google.com"},
      {id: 5, state: "Alabama", district: "5th District", url:"www.google.com"},
      {id: 6, state: "Alabama", district: "6th District", url:"www.google.com"},
      {id: 7, state: "Alabama", district: "7th District", url:"www.google.com"},
      {id: 9, state: "Alaska", district: "Statewide District", url:"www.google.com"},
      {id: 10, state: "Arizona", district: "1st District", url:"www.google.com"},
      {id: 11, state: "Arizona", district: "2nd District", url:"www.google.com"},
      {id: 12, state: "Arizona", district: "3rd District", url:"www.google.com"},
```

There are more states but above is just a snippet.

```
<body>
    <div class="container55">
      <h2>Find Out How Tax Reform Will Impact Your District</h2>
        <select id="listed_states">
          <option>Find Your District Here</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </body>


   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  //Code block generating dropdown list from states object
      for (let i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
       if (states[i].id > 0) {
        var option = $("<option>", {
         text: states[i].state + " " + states[i].district,
         value: states[i].id
       });
      $('#listed_states').append($(option));
    }
  }



  $('#listed_states').on('change', function(){
   if ($(this).url){
    window.open($(this).url, '_blank');
   } else {
    console.log('false');
   }
  })
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: You're not associating the `url` from your `states` array with your `<option>` elements. That information is just staying unused in your array. You could either pass it forward as a `data attribute` or go back to the array to read the URL after the `change` event fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option missing url  and you change $(this).url with $(this).find('option:selected').attr('url')

```
//Code block generating dropdown list from states object
          for (let i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
           if (states[i].id > 0) {
            var option = $("<option>", {
             text: states[i].state + " " + states[i].district,
             value: states[i].id,
             url : states[i].url
           });
          $('#listed_states').append($(option));
        }
      }



      $('#listed_states').on('change', function(){
       if ($(this).find('option:selected').attr('url')){
        window.open($(this).find('option:selected').attr('url'), '_blank');
       } else {
        console.log('false');
       }
      })
     });
```

https://codepen.io/piscu/pen/eeGzBP

Comment: This is close but the url path is wherever you're working from plus www.google.com. Yours for code pen would be: https://codepen.io/boomerang/iFrameKey-d75ac767-3298-4621-99fc-23669e18dc49/www.google.com. Is there any way to change this so you just open the url as it is in the object?

Comment: @OsuDani url must be with http:// http://www.google.com not www.google.com

Comment: I just figured that out as I was playing with it. Thanks again! :)